# Core Data crash: Collection was mutated while being enumerated

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

My app seems to be crashing when I try to perform a fetch. I'm using magical records. The error message is:

> Collection <__NSCFSet: 0x17005a1f0> was mutated while being enumerated.

To me this indicates that we're changing objects in the context while performing the fetch, but I'm new to this so I might be wrong.

Here's the code it's pointing at:

```
- (void) buildAndFetchFRCsInContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context{

[context performBlock:^{
    __unused NSDate* start = [NSDate date];

    self.contactsFRC = [self buildFetchResultsControllerForClass:[Contact class] sortedBy:@"id" withPredicate:nil inContext:context];
    self.callsFRC = [self buildFetchResultsControllerForClass:[Call class] sortedBy:@"id" withPredicate:nil inContext:context];
    self.newsItemsFRC = [self buildFetchResultsControllerForClass:[NewsItem class] sortedBy:@"id" withPredicate:nil inContext:context]; 

    NSError* error;

    // Peform the fetches
    [self.contactsFRC performFetch:&error];
    [self.callsFRC performFetch:&error];
    [self.newsItemsFRC performFetch:&error]; //Crash points to this line
    NSLog(@"Spent [%@s] performing fetchs for counts!", @(fabs([start timeIntervalSinceNow])));

    [self calculateAndBroadcastCounts];
}];
}
```

The context being passed in is:

```
- (instancetype) initWithUserSession:(BPDUserSession*)userSession{
    self = [super init];
    ...
    self.context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];
    [self buildAndFetchFRCsInContext:self.context];
    ...
}
```

What I think is that this class is being initialized in the main thread, but performBlock adds the block to a queue and then executes from a different thread. But I don't think this is true because the purpose of performBlock is to perform that block on another thread.

From what I've posted, can anyone tell what the issue is?

## Update:

I tried moving the `buildFetchResultsController` call to outside of the perform block:

```
- (void) buildAndFetchFRCsInContext:(NSManagedObjectContext*)context{
self.contactsFRC = [self buildFetchResultsControllerForClass:[Contact class] sortedBy:@"id" withPredicate:nil inContext:context];
self.callsFRC = [self buildFetchResultsControllerForClass:[Call class] sortedBy:@"id" withPredicate:nil inContext:context];
self.newsItemsFRC = [self buildFetchResultsControllerForClass:[NewsItem class] sortedBy:@"id" withPredicate:nil inContext:context];

NSMutableArray *list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:100];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    list[i] = [self buildFetchResultsControllerForClass:[NewsItem class] sortedBy:@"id" withPredicate:nil inContext:context];
}

[context performBlock:^{
    __unused NSDate* start = [NSDate date];

    NSError* error;

    // Peform the fetches
    [self.contactsFRC performFetch:&error];
    [self.callsFRC performFetch:&error];
    [self.newsItemsFRC performFetch:&error];

    for (int i = 0; i < list.count; i++) {
        [list[i] performFetch:&error]; // Generally error is thrown on i = 5 ~> 10
    }

    NSLog(@"Spent [%@s] performing fetchs for counts!", @(fabs([start timeIntervalSinceNow])));

    [self calculateAndBroadcastCounts];
}];
}
```

but this still fails. I'm able to reproduce the failure with the loop shown above. I also tried creating a new context to use from within the actual performBlock closure with `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` but this didn't work either, same issue.

Note: I'm using MagicalRecords, so for those of you who aren't familiar, `[NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];` is equivalent to the context returned from:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[self alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType]; // Here self is NSManagedObjectContext
[context setParentContext:parentContext];
[context MR_obtainPermanentIDsBeforeSaving];
return context;
```

Comment: This looks like you are enumerating a set at some point using syntax like `for (MyClass *object in objects)` then in the body of this loop you are modifying (add/delete etc) `objects`

Comment: Yea that's what the exception means. But that doesn't make any sense because, as you can see, there are no loops anywhere within this code structure. The error is being thrown after the fetch request is called

Comment: Which line exactly is it breaking on?

Comment: Sorry I included a reference to the line in a later edit but here it is:
```[self.newsItemsFRC performFetch:&error]; ```

Comment: Does it make sense to create fetchedResultsController in a background context? I'm assuming they should be on the main thread if they are going to drive UI

Comment: You're right we do use it to make UI, so that part is fine. I think I know the issue: ```...inContext:context``` I use the context thats performing performBlock to perform another fetch. But this fetch will be called from any thread, so hence the issue. But how do I reproduce this error?

Comment: is `buildFetchResultsControllerForClass` asynchronous?

Comment: Yes? I think so, I never defined it otherwise so it must be

Comment: Your use of context seems ok as you are doing it within a performBlock. I'm questioning whether it's safe to use a background context for a fetched results controller that works on UI - do you get the issue if you use the main context to create the fetchedResultsContrillers?

Comment: Just to be clear, this is indirectly updating UI by sending out notifications and then other classes respond to these notifications. Even then it's not crashing on any UI update, it's crashing on execution of the fetch request, aka ```[self.newsItemsFRC performFetch:&error]```. So you mean move the buildfetchresultscontroller call to outside perform block? Then perform the fetch from inside performBlock?

Comment: Is it possible that a save or merge into the parent context of the private context (aka ```context.parent```)  is what's causing the error? How can I figure out all other fetches/saves performed from other threads/on other contexts?

Comment: Can you share the stack trace of the crash? If it's crashing on the line you're saying then the set that is being manipulated and enumerated at the same time is internal to the Core Data framework, which probably means you're doing something wrong with concurrency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My issue was I was performing a save on a context and that save had concurrency issues, I was trying to save objects created on the main thread from a thread that wasn't main. Moving that code to the main thread fixed the crash.

Comment: Which code you moved to the main thread? The code where you write the data in database or the code that you save the data in database ?

Comment: Neither the actual creation of the context is what I moved: `NSManagedObjectContext context = [NSManagedObjectContext ...]`  -> move to the main thread